# Which to use: REMOTE_ADDR or SERVER_ADDR

Tags: php

Any real difference between

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']
```

I'm tracking visitors to a page, and I've always used `REMOTE_ADDR`, but recently I saw a script that collected both information. Is this a better practice or not needed?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`SERVER_ADDR` is the address of the server PHP code is run on. You don't need to collect it. `REMOTE_ADDR` is the one you want.

Comment: SERVER_ADDR would only be relevant if the site's hosted on multiple servers and you're interested in exactly which server handled the request.

Comment: `SERVER` / `REMOTE` are self explanatory :/

Answer (score 36):

The `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` returns the IP address ***from which the user is viewing the current page***. And `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` returns the IP address of the ***server under which the current script is executing***.

**So what should you use:**

You should use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

**More Info:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score -2):

IP to use for API and online payment gateway: `$ _SERVER ['SERVER_ADDR']`

Returns the user's address from which they are viewing the current page `$_SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it