# What is the difference between 'REMOTE_ADDR' and 'SERVER_ADDR' in php?

Tags: php, ip-address

Just went through php manual it says

> 'SERVER_ADDR'
>       The IP address of the server under which the current script is executing.
>
> 'REMOTE_ADDR'
>       The IP address from which the user is viewing the current page.

To someone like me with little knowledge of programming they mean same thing i.e, to get IP address. So which should I use to simply get IP address of client visiting my site?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which to use: REMOTE\_ADDR or SERVER\_ADDR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394367/which-to-use-remote-addr-or-server-addr)

Comment: The phrase `from which the user is viewing the current page` doesn't give you any clues?

Comment: @MarkBaker no because script might also be executing on same

Comment: PHP SCRIPTS DO NOT EXECUTE IN THE USER'S BROWSER, they execute on the web server.... the only time the to addresses would be the same is if the user is actually running a browser on the web server.... and that's only ever likely to be you

Answer (score 6):

Let's say that you have a php program (or script, call it how you want) that is running on a server, and you access that script from your home computer. Then, in this case:

```
SERVER_ADDR is the IP address of the server on which the script is located and ran
REMOTE_ADDR is the IP address of the computer that sent the request (e.g your home computer)
```